# How to put a picture instead of a video in CSS?

Tags: html, css

There are 3 videos in the carousel, in CSS i wrote media query `display:none;` for devices who has screen less than 600px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .video {
overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
      display: none;

}
```

Is it possible to make so that who have a display less 600px saw the picture, rest saw a video?

Comment: Certainly it's possible, you are in the right track, just use the @media screen then create another set of images that will show when the screen is equals to what you have set.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it can be possible,

> Is it possible to make so that who have a display less 600px saw the picture, rest saw a video?
>
> There are 3 videos in the carousel, in CSS i wrote media query display:none; for devices who has screen less than 600px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.video {
display:none;
}
.image{
//add here your css for image
}
}
```

For videos

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.video {
    //add here your css for video
}
.image{
 display:none;

}
}
```

Their are many ways to do this thing and above is one of that

Answer (score 1):

You can use (min) and (max-width) for more info you can check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Targeting_media_features):

`@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` and `@media screen and (min-width: 600px)`

with `display:none` to hide and `block` in this example to show.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .video {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    /* width: 100%; *//*<< double declaration*/
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: none;
  } /*<< missing closing .video bracket*/
  .pic {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .video {
    display: block;
  }
  .pic {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Picture" height="320" width="480" class="pic">

<video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGFSjKuJfrI" class="video" controls>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: what if i have a few pictures?

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to let multiple pictures shown/hidden just add the class.

Comment: Notice that `<img>` in example above has `class="pic"`

Comment: i have a slider with 4 videos, i want to replace videos with pictures when user comes with mobile device

Comment: so i need to create classes for each pictures?

Comment: Preferably yes. Since if you target all img it would affect every picture in your html. See the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ybt1pmk9/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ybt1pmk9/embedded/result for full size.

it had 4 video and image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191709/discussion-between-arsen-ospanov-and-shinjo).